# Can I have multiple controls in an ActiveX project / DLL?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, activex, ocx

I have an OCX (DLL) developed in Visual Basic 6.0. This OCX has several controls within the project, and I 
am converting or translating that OCX to Visual C++ 2012.

So far I can create a MFC ActiveX project with the
wizard and it works, but I have not found a way to add a different controls to the same OCX , 
so I do not know if that is even possible in Visual C++ 2012, because I want to have a single ActiveX OCX / DLL
with all the controls inside as the OCX is to maintain compatibility cause I want to replace the
OCX with a new version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add MFC ActiveX control to an existing activex project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151622/how-do-i-add-mfc-activex-control-to-an-existing-activex-project)

Answer (score 0):

You will find what you are looking for in the Project menu -> Add Class...

[image: add ATL control]

Comment: You can add a new class by doing that, but not another activeX control to the same project.

Comment: @Alejandro Vega: You don't get something like this (see screenshot above, taken from a VS2008)?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dialog in your ActiveX control and put multiple controls on the dialog, just like any other dialog. If you don't want it to look like a dialog then turn off the titlebar and border styles on the dialog template. This will give you a child window that the user cannot move and it should blend in visually with the parent window.

Comment: the idea is to have several custom made activeX on the project, not to place controls in a dialog box.

Comment: Your original question said "I want to have a single ActiveX...". So you latest comment confuses things.